# Firebase function not returning data

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get data from my Firebase function, but it keeps returning a null response. It looks like I need to return a promise and return my data in that promise, but I can't seem to get it to work even though I think I'm doing that. I'm not the most familiar with Node.JS, so I might be returning the wrong things in the promise.

Here's my function code:

```
exports.tasksLists = functions.region('us-east1').https.onCall((data) => {
  const userDoc = db.collection('users').doc(data.text);
  return userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return doc.data().tasksKey;
    }
  }).then((tasksCreds) => {
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      '444701140384-srcttdrg28geg598h65dkekad47u9a48.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'wNL4ZrBGYOnXUMvEcE7Z_Smo',
      'https://collag-oauth-u5b2i5chyq-ue.a.run.app/classroomcallback'
    );
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: tasksCreds.refresh_token,
      access_token: tasksCreds.token
    });
    const service = google.tasks({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });
    return service.tasklists.list({}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        functions.logger.error(new Error(err));
        return JSON.stringify(err);
      }
      const lists = res.data.items;
      if (lists) {
        functions.logger.info(lists);
        return lists;
      } else {
        functions.logger.info('no lists');
        return "No lists";
      }
    });
  })
    .catch((e) => {
      functions.logger.error(new Error(e));
      return JSON.stringify(e);
    });;

});
```

I've also tried putting the OAuth and API request in the first `.then()` under `else` but that didn't work either.

Here's my frontend code to call the function and handle the data:

```
let tasksLists = fireApp.functions('us-east1').httpsCallable('tasksLists');
          tasksLists({ text: currentUser.uid }).then(function (result) {
            if (!result.data) {
              console.log('no data');
            }
            let lists = result.data;
            console.log(lists);
          });
```

The `console.log(lists)` just outputs null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning a promise. You can use the Promise constructor, passing in the `resolve`/`reject` parameters and call any of those when your want to return the asynchronous result. Change your cloud function like so:

```js
exports.tasksLists = functions.region('us-east1').https.onCall((data) => {
  const userDoc = db.collection('users').doc(data.text);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return doc.data().tasksKey;
    }
  }).then((tasksCreds) => {
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      '444701140384-srcttdrg28geg598h65dkekad47u9a48.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'wNL4ZrBGYOnXUMvEcE7Z_Smo',
      'https://collag-oauth-u5b2i5chyq-ue.a.run.app/classroomcallback'
    );
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: tasksCreds.refresh_token,
      access_token: tasksCreds.token
    });
    const service = google.tasks({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });
    service.tasklists.list({}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        functions.logger.error(new Error(err));
        // return JSON.stringify(err);
        reject(err);
      }
      const lists = res.data.items;
      if (lists) {
        functions.logger.info(lists);
        resolve(lists);
        // return lists;
      } else {
        functions.logger.info('no lists');
        resolve("No lists")
        // return "No lists";
      }
    });
  })
    .catch((e) => {
      functions.logger.error(new Error(e));
      reject(e);
      // return JSON.stringify(e);
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I thought I was already returning a promise with `userDoc.get()` but I guess not.