# Firebase function not returning value

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do some operations using oncall function where,
I am first checking if user exists in database, then if he exists then do some operations like updating the DB.
well the function is working as expected and updating the DB as well, but its returning response as null so I can't tell what exactly happening.

```
exports.populateCart = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const user = context.auth.uid;

    DB.collection('users').doc(user).get().then((usr_resp) => {
        if (usr_resp.exists) {
            DB.collection('products').doc(data.productKey).get().then((prod_res) => {
                DB.collection('carts').add({
                    //some data
                }).then(() => {
                    return {
                        response: 'CART UPDATED'
                    };
                }).catch((carts_err) => {
                    return {
                        response: 'ERROR WHILE POPULATING CART : ' + carts_err
                    }
                });
            }).catch((prod_err) => {
                return {
                    response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING PRODUCT : ' + prod_err
                };
            });
        }
        else {
            return {
                response: 'USER DOES NOT EXISTS OR USER NOT AUTHENTICATED'
            };
        }
    }).catch((usr_err) => {
        return {
            response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING USER : ' + usr_err
        };
    });
});
```

There is one more similar question on stack overflow, where the solution is proposed to use,

```
reject(err);
resolve(lists);
```

methods, Please if the solution is using above methods, then please explain the use cases of this method in detail and if there are more methods like this please explain them as well.

[Firebase function not returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460098/firebase-function-not-returning-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return ***every*** promise that you are running:

```
exports.populateCart = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const user = context.auth.uid;

    return DB.collection('users').doc(user).get().then((usr_resp) => {
        if (usr_resp.exists) {
            return DB.collection('products').doc(data.productKey).get().then((prod_res) => {
                return DB.collection('carts').add({
                    //some data
                }).then(() => {
                    return {
                        response: 'CART UPDATED'
                    };
                }).catch((carts_err) => {
                    return {
                        response: 'ERROR WHILE POPULATING CART : ' + carts_err
                    }
                });
            }).catch((prod_err) => {
                return {
                    response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING PRODUCT : ' + prod_err
                };
            });
        }
        else {
            return {
                response: 'USER DOES NOT EXISTS OR USER NOT AUTHENTICATED'
            };
        }
    }).catch((usr_err) => {
        return {
            response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING USER : ' + usr_err
        };
    });
});
```

Try copying the above code. Also using async functions will make it look better like this:

```
exports.populateCart = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const usr_resp = await DB.collection('users').doc(user).get()
    if (!usr_resp.exists) throw new Error("USER DOES NOT EXISTS OR USER NOT AUTHENTICATED")
    const prod_res = await DB.collection('products').doc(data.productKey).get()
    await DB.collection('carts').add({ . someData . })
    return { response: "Cart Updated" }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return { response: e }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning your promise. (see line 3 below)

```
exports.populateCart = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const user = context.auth.uid;
    // add return here before Db.collection()
    return DB.collection('users').doc(user).get().then((usr_resp) => { 
        if (usr_resp.exists) {
            return DB.collection('products').doc(data.productKey).get().then((prod_res) => {
              return  DB.collection('carts').add({
                    //some data
                }).then(() => {
                    return {
                        response: 'CART UPDATED'
                    };
                }).catch((carts_err) => {
                    return {
                        response: 'ERROR WHILE POPULATING CART : ' + carts_err
                    }
                });
            }).catch((prod_err) => {
                return {
                    response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING PRODUCT : ' + prod_err
                };
            });
        }
        else {
            return {
                response: 'USER DOES NOT EXISTS OR USER NOT AUTHENTICATED'
            };
        }
    }).catch((usr_err) => {
        return {
            response: 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING USER : ' + usr_err
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: I commented line 3, you need to return the promise.

Comment: add return at `DB.collection('carts')`  as well as  DB.collection('collections')also, just make sure u return all the promises.

Comment: This is the problem of using chain promises. If it's complicated then you need to learn how to use async/await instead.

Comment: Yes I was aware of the issue, of using chain promise, and using await and async calls, but I forgot the syntaxes